# Problem loading COCO weights to Mask R-CNN on NVIDIA Jetson TX2: Resource Exhausted

Tags: python, tensorflow, faster-rcnn, nvidia-jetson, mscoco

I am currently using a NVIDIA Jetson TX2 with Ubuntu 18.04 to train a Mask R-CNN (Matterport implementation https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN) with my custom dataset. When I try to load the `mask_rcnn_coco.h5`, the following error comes up multiple times:

```
2019-11-11 10:47:36.177422: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1502] OP_REQUIRES failed at random_op.cc:76 : Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[7,7,256,1024] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
2019-11-11 10:47:46.178504: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:314] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 36.8KiB (rounded to 37632).  Current allocation summary follows.
2019-11-11 10:47:46.178985: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:764] Bin (256):   Total Chunks: 52, Chunks in use: 52. 13.0KiB allocated for chunks. 13.0KiB in use in bin. 808B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-11 10:47:46.179255: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:764] Bin (512):   Total Chunks: 2, Chunks in use: 2. 1.0KiB allocated for chunks. 1.0KiB in use in bin. 1.0KiB client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-11 10:47:46.179435: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:764] Bin (1024):  Total Chunks: 3, Chunks in use: 3. 3.2KiB allocated for chunks. 3.2KiB in use in bin. 3.0KiB client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-11 10:47:46.179565: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:764] Bin (2048):  Total Chunks: 2, Chunks in use: 2. 4.0KiB allocated for chunks. 4.0KiB in use in bin. 4.0KiB client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-11 10:47:46.179697: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:764] Bin (4096):  Total Chunks: 2, Chunks in use: 2. 8.0KiB allocated for chunks. 8.0KiB in use in bin. 8.0KiB client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-11 10:47:46.179835: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:764] Bin (8192):  Total Chunks: 3, Chunks in use: 3. 28.0KiB allocated for chunks. 28.0KiB in use in bin. 28.0KiB client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-11 10:47:46.179964: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:764] Bin (16384):     Total Chunks: 1, Chunks in use: 1. 16.0KiB allocated for chunks. 16.0KiB in use in bin. 16.0KiB client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-11 10:47:46.180097: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:764] Bin (32768):     Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-11 10:47:46.180374: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:764] Bin (65536):     Total Chunks: 6, Chunks in use: 6. 384.0KiB allocated for chunks. 384.0KiB in use in bin. 384.0KiB client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-11 10:47:46.180655: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:764] Bin (131072):    Total Chunks: 4, Chunks in use: 4. 560.0KiB allocated for chunks. 560.0KiB in use in bin. 560.0KiB client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-11 10:47:46.180810: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:764] Bin (262144):    Total Chunks: 7, Chunks in use: 7. 1.75MiB allocated for chunks. 1.75MiB in use in bin. 1.75MiB client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-11 10:47:46.180939: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:764] Bin (524288):    Total Chunks: 7, Chunks in use: 7. 3.75MiB allocated for chunks. 3.75MiB in use in bin. 3.75MiB client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-11 10:47:46.181089: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:764] Bin (1048576):   Total Chunks: 2, Chunks in use: 2. 2.53MiB allocated for chunks. 2.53MiB in use in bin. 2.00MiB client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-11 10:47:46.181306: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:764] Bin (2097152):   Total Chunks: 1, Chunks in use: 1. 2.00MiB allocated for chunks. 2.00MiB in use in bin. 2.00MiB client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-11 10:47:46.181414: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:764] Bin (4194304):   Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-11 10:47:46.181519: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:764] Bin (8388608):   Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-11 10:47:46.181694: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:764] Bin (16777216):  Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-11 10:47:46.181826: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:764] Bin (33554432):  Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-11 10:47:46.181937: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:764] Bin (67108864):  Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-11 10:47:46.182080: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:764] Bin (134217728):     Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-11 10:47:46.182290: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:764] Bin (268435456):     Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-11 10:47:46.182397: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:780] Bin for 36.8KiB was 32.0KiB, Chunk State: 
2019-11-11 10:47:46.182479: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:793] Next region of size 11554816
2019-11-11 10:47:46.182572: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e60000 next 1 of size 1280
2019-11-11 10:47:46.182720: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e60500 next 2 of size 256
2019-11-11 10:47:46.182806: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e60600 next 3 of size 256
2019-11-11 10:47:46.182886: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e60700 next 4 of size 2048
2019-11-11 10:47:46.182964: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e60f00 next 5 of size 256
2019-11-11 10:47:46.183044: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e61000 next 6 of size 256
2019-11-11 10:47:46.183122: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e61100 next 7 of size 256
2019-11-11 10:47:46.183198: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e61200 next 8 of size 256
2019-11-11 10:47:46.183300: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e61300 next 9 of size 256
2019-11-11 10:47:46.183481: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e61400 next 10 of size 256
2019-11-11 10:47:46.183567: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e61500 next 11 of size 256
2019-11-11 10:47:46.183646: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e61600 next 12 of size 256
2019-11-11 10:47:46.183722: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e61700 next 13 of size 8192
2019-11-11 10:47:46.183803: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e63700 next 14 of size 256
2019-11-11 10:47:46.183938: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e63800 next 15 of size 256
2019-11-11 10:47:46.184040: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e63900 next 16 of size 256
2019-11-11 10:47:46.184124: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e63a00 next 17 of size 256
2019-11-11 10:47:46.184230: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e63b00 next 18 of size 256
2019-11-11 10:47:46.184312: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e63c00 next 19 of size 256
2019-11-11 10:47:46.184417: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e63d00 next 20 of size 256
2019-11-11 10:47:46.184501: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e63e00 next 21 of size 256
2019-11-11 10:47:46.184643: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e63f00 next 22 of size 4096
2019-11-11 10:47:46.184727: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e64f00 next 23 of size 256
2019-11-11 10:47:46.184833: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e65000 next 24 of size 256
2019-11-11 10:47:46.185067: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e65100 next 25 of size 1024
2019-11-11 10:47:46.185154: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e65500 next 26 of size 256
2019-11-11 10:47:46.185231: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e65600 next 27 of size 256
2019-11-11 10:47:46.185312: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e65700 next 28 of size 256
2019-11-11 10:47:46.185389: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e65800 next 29 of size 256
2019-11-11 10:47:46.185477: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e65900 next 30 of size 256
2019-11-11 10:47:46.185557: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e65a00 next 31 of size 256
2019-11-11 10:47:46.185670: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e65b00 next 32 of size 512
2019-11-11 10:47:46.185753: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e65d00 next 33 of size 256
2019-11-11 10:47:46.185830: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e65e00 next 34 of size 256
2019-11-11 10:47:46.185907: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e65f00 next 35 of size 256
2019-11-11 10:47:46.185985: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e66000 next 36 of size 256
2019-11-11 10:47:46.186062: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e66100 next 37 of size 256
2019-11-11 10:47:46.186172: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e66200 next 38 of size 256
2019-11-11 10:47:46.186254: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e66300 next 39 of size 256
2019-11-11 10:47:46.186333: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e66400 next 40 of size 256
2019-11-11 10:47:46.186414: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e66500 next 41 of size 256
2019-11-11 10:47:46.186612: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e66600 next 42 of size 256
2019-11-11 10:47:46.186682: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e66700 next 43 of size 256
2019-11-11 10:47:46.186747: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e66800 next 44 of size 1024
2019-11-11 10:47:46.186833: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e66c00 next 45 of size 256
2019-11-11 10:47:46.186896: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e66d00 next 46 of size 256
2019-11-11 10:47:46.186956: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e66e00 next 47 of size 256
2019-11-11 10:47:46.187017: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e66f00 next 48 of size 256
2019-11-11 10:47:46.187078: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e67000 next 49 of size 256
2019-11-11 10:47:46.187138: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e67100 next 50 of size 256
2019-11-11 10:47:46.187198: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e67200 next 51 of size 256
2019-11-11 10:47:46.187262: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e67300 next 52 of size 4096
2019-11-11 10:47:46.187322: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e68300 next 53 of size 256
2019-11-11 10:47:46.187382: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e68400 next 54 of size 256
2019-11-11 10:47:46.187441: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e68500 next 55 of size 256
2019-11-11 10:47:46.187501: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e68600 next 56 of size 256
2019-11-11 10:47:46.187567: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e68700 next 57 of size 256
2019-11-11 10:47:46.187628: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e68800 next 58 of size 256
2019-11-11 10:47:46.187688: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e68900 next 59 of size 256
2019-11-11 10:47:46.187748: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e68a00 next 60 of size 256
2019-11-11 10:47:46.187806: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e68b00 next 61 of size 8192
2019-11-11 10:47:46.187866: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e6ab00 next 62 of size 2048
2019-11-11 10:47:46.187926: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e6b300 next 63 of size 512
2019-11-11 10:47:46.187987: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00e6b500 next 64 of size 524288
2019-11-11 10:47:46.188046: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00eeb500 next 65 of size 524288
2019-11-11 10:47:46.188105: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00f6b500 next 66 of size 589824
2019-11-11 10:47:46.188163: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf00ffb500 next 67 of size 589824
2019-11-11 10:47:46.188222: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf0108b500 next 68 of size 589824
2019-11-11 10:47:46.188280: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf0111b500 next 69 of size 589824
2019-11-11 10:47:46.188338: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf011ab500 next 70 of size 2097152
2019-11-11 10:47:46.188401: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf013ab500 next 71 of size 262144
2019-11-11 10:47:46.188460: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf013eb500 next 72 of size 262144
2019-11-11 10:47:46.188518: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf0142b500 next 73 of size 262144
2019-11-11 10:47:46.188576: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf0146b500 next 74 of size 262144
2019-11-11 10:47:46.188646: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf014ab500 next 75 of size 131072
2019-11-11 10:47:46.188707: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf014cb500 next 76 of size 65536
2019-11-11 10:47:46.188768: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf014db500 next 77 of size 65536
2019-11-11 10:47:46.188828: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf014eb500 next 78 of size 65536
2019-11-11 10:47:46.188886: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf014fb500 next 79 of size 65536
2019-11-11 10:47:46.188946: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf0150b500 next 80 of size 262144
2019-11-11 10:47:46.189004: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf0154b500 next 81 of size 262144
2019-11-11 10:47:46.189062: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf0158b500 next 82 of size 262144
2019-11-11 10:47:46.189120: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf015cb500 next 83 of size 524288
2019-11-11 10:47:46.189179: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf0164b500 next 84 of size 65536
2019-11-11 10:47:46.189237: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf0165b500 next 85 of size 65536
2019-11-11 10:47:46.189299: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf0166b500 next 86 of size 16384
2019-11-11 10:47:46.189358: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf0166f500 next 87 of size 1048576
2019-11-11 10:47:46.189419: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf0176f500 next 88 of size 147456
2019-11-11 10:47:46.189477: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf01793500 next 89 of size 147456
2019-11-11 10:47:46.189534: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf017b7500 next 90 of size 147456
2019-11-11 10:47:46.189593: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf017db500 next 91 of size 12288
2019-11-11 10:47:46.189716: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:800] InUse at 0xf017de500 next 18446744073709551615 of size 1600256
2019-11-11 10:47:46.189777: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:809]      Summary of in-use Chunks by size: 
2019-11-11 10:47:46.189845: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:812] 52 Chunks of size 256 totalling 13.0KiB
2019-11-11 10:47:46.189911: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:812] 2 Chunks of size 512 totalling 1.0KiB
2019-11-11 10:47:46.189976: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:812] 2 Chunks of size 1024 totalling 2.0KiB
2019-11-11 10:47:46.190040: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:812] 1 Chunks of size 1280 totalling 1.2KiB
2019-11-11 10:47:46.190103: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:812] 2 Chunks of size 2048 totalling 4.0KiB
2019-11-11 10:47:46.190168: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:812] 2 Chunks of size 4096 totalling 8.0KiB
2019-11-11 10:47:46.190232: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:812] 2 Chunks of size 8192 totalling 16.0KiB
2019-11-11 10:47:46.190295: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:812] 1 Chunks of size 12288 totalling 12.0KiB
2019-11-11 10:47:46.190359: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:812] 1 Chunks of size 16384 totalling 16.0KiB
2019-11-11 10:47:46.190425: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:812] 6 Chunks of size 65536 totalling 384.0KiB
2019-11-11 10:47:46.190491: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:812] 1 Chunks of size 131072 totalling 128.0KiB
2019-11-11 10:47:46.190586: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:812] 3 Chunks of size 147456 totalling 432.0KiB
2019-11-11 10:47:46.190654: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:812] 7 Chunks of size 262144 totalling 1.75MiB
2019-11-11 10:47:46.190722: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:812] 3 Chunks of size 524288 totalling 1.50MiB
2019-11-11 10:47:46.190785: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:812] 4 Chunks of size 589824 totalling 2.25MiB
2019-11-11 10:47:46.190847: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:812] 1 Chunks of size 1048576 totalling 1.00MiB
2019-11-11 10:47:46.190908: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:812] 1 Chunks of size 1600256 totalling 1.53MiB
2019-11-11 10:47:46.190970: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:812] 1 Chunks of size 2097152 totalling 2.00MiB
2019-11-11 10:47:46.191033: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:816] Sum Total of in-use chunks: 11.02MiB
2019-11-11 10:47:46.191094: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:818] total_region_allocated_bytes_: 11554816 memory_limit_: 11554816 available bytes: 0 curr_region_allocation_bytes_: 23109632
2019-11-11 10:47:46.191203: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:824] Stats: 
Limit:                    11554816
InUse:                    11554816
MaxInUse:                 11554816
NumAllocs:                      92
MaxAllocSize:              2097152
```

The same error appears in many topics when training the model, but here I am just trying to load the pre-trained weights. I am not understanding why only a small piece of memory is being employed.

Comment: The error is due to unavailability of enough memory. You can try building a smaller model or reduce batch size. This must help.

Comment: The problem is not building the model, I get the error when trying to load the coco-weights. This file amount around 260 Mb, this should not be a problem for an 8 Gb GPU, should it?

Comment: Do check with `nvidia-smi` command and see if any process has already used your GPU